# Opencl loops in kernel

Tags: opencl, reduction

In the code block there is my kernel function. It essentialy calculates which point is the farthest from all clusters and results are saved in lengths[3] (id of the point) and output[0] the distance from the belonging cluster. The while piece does a simple sum reduction. I know it is not the best method to do but I need to understand why having one cluster the code works properly insteas with two or more clusters return wrong values.

```
__kernel void computeDistances(__global t_cluster *points,__global t_cluster *clusters,     __global float *output,__global t_cluster *support,__global short *lengths)
{
    int threadId = get_global_id(0);
    float bestVal = 0;
    int counter, offset;

    short idPoint, idCluster;
    for(idPoint = 0; idPoint < lengths[0]; idPoint++)
    {

        for(idCluster = 0; idCluster < lengths[2]; idCluster++)
        {     
            support[0].attributes[threadId] = pow( (points[idPoint].attributes[threadId] - clusters[idCluster].attributes[threadId]) , 2 );

            counter = SIZE;
            offset = 1;

            while(counter != 1)
            {
                counter = counter / 2 + (counter % 2);

                barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);

                if(threadId % (2*offset) == 0)
                    if(threadId + offset < lengths[1])
                        support[0].attributes[threadId] = support[0].attributes[threadId] + support[0].attributes[threadId+offset];

                offset = offset * 2 ;
             }

             barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);

            if(support[0].attributes[threadId] > bestVal)
                bestVal = support[0].attributes[threadId];

    }

    barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);

    if(threadId == 0 && bestVal > output[threadId])
    {
        output[0] = bestVal;
        lengths[3] = idPoint;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using Barriers which cannot be used to synchronise across multiple compute cores (work groups).

*Barrier synchronisation only works within the same logical work group*. See [this post on Khronos](http://www.khronos.org/message_boards/showthread.php/6221-Global-Barriers) to get a better idea of what I am referring to.

Increasing your cluster size also increases the number of work items in use, which probably then makes use of more than one work group which is why you are experiencing this issue.

*EDIT*: Its probably worth pointing out that no synchronisation primitives can be used across workgroups.